# В чем разница места создания BufferedReader при создании нового потока?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я создаю внутренний статический класс, наследую его от `Thread`. Новая нить должна считывать с консоли, например числа и суммировать их. В чем разница, где создавать `BufferedReader` - до метода `run()` или в нем?

```
public static class TestThread5 extends Thread {
        int sum = 0;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // здесь создать     

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // или здесь
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String str = reader.readLine();
                    if (!str.equals("N")) {
                        sum += Integer.valueOf(str);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(sum);
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: в общем-то никакой.разницы

Comment: Если BufferReader создать перед run(), после завершения run() BufferReader вернет ресурсы?

Comment: Как только нигде в вашем приложении не останется ссылки на экземпляр `TestThread5`, все его члены, включая поле `reader`, станут доступны сборщику мусора.

Comment: @Gennadyi закрыть поток чтения надо самому, т.к. BR это просто обертка

Answer (score 1):

Разница конечно же есть.

В первом варианте, когда `BufferedReader` создается вне `run()` он по сути создается совместно с созданием экземпляра класса `TestThread5`, во втором варианте он создается только при запуске треда/нити.

Чувствуете разницу? Еще нет?

**Объясняю:** если вы будете использовать объект класса `TestThread5` только 1 раз - никакой разницы не будет. Но как только вы решите повторно использовать этот объект разница всплывет наружу (например запустите тред повторно). В первом случае вы будете заново использовать старый `BufferedReader`, который возможно будет содержать непустой буфер, а во втором случае `BufferedReader` будет новеньким - соответственно буфер будет пуст.

Comment: А поток вообще возможно запустить повторно?

Comment: `Thread.start()` - запускает во второй раз, но если тред еще не завершен, то выкинется `IllegalThreadStateException` - можно проверить через `isAlive()`

Comment: второй раз не запускается

Comment: Из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()): *It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution*

Comment: Можно переиспользовать имплементацию `Runnable`, но не `Thread`.